# How to set the width of a ui.input

Tags: nicegui

https://nicegui.io/documentation/input

shows the example:

```py
from nicegui import ui

ui.input(label='Text', placeholder='start typing',
         on_change=lambda e: result.set_text('you typed: ' + e.value),
         validation={'Input too long': lambda value: len(value) < 20})
result = ui.label()

ui.run()
```

And has 4 Inherited from

- ValueElement
- DisableableElement
- Element
- Visibility

where the documenation is unforunately not "linked/clickabel".

I wonder how the size of the input can be manipulated. I tried in justpy style just setting "size=80" in the constructor but that doesn't work.

**How can the size be set properly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
input=ui.input(...)
input.props("size=80")
```

works

Comment: then how to change the height?